# Fix warning: Missing argument

Tags: themes, filters, errors, actions, debug

i want to submit a theme to the wordpress.org. when i put the `define('WP_DEBUG', true);` in my `wp-config.php`. my theme showed some errors.but i don't know how to correct theme.

Q1:`Warning: Missing argument 2 for cutstr() in ....htdocs\wordpress\wp-content\themes\warm-home\functions.php on line 156`. the following is my function.

```
function cutstr($string, $length) {
         $string =strip_tags($string);
        preg_match_all("/[x01-x7f]|[xc2-xdf][x80-xbf]|xe0[xa0-xbf][x80-xbf]|
[xe1-xef][x80-xbf][x80-xbf]|xf0[x90-xbf][x80-xbf][x80-xbf]|[xf1-xf7][x80-xbf][x80-xbf][x80-xbf]/", $string, $info);  
         for($i=0; $i<count($info[0]); $i++) {
                $wordscut= '';
                $wordscut .= $info[0][$i];
                $j='';
                $j = ord($info[0][$i]) > 127 ? $j + 2 : $j + 1;
                 if ($j > $length - 3) {
                         return $wordscut." ...";
                 }
         }
         return join('', $info[0]);
}
add_action('after_setup_theme','cutstr');
```

invoked the function line is: `<p><?php echo cutstr($post->post_content,150) ?></p>`.there is no Missing argument 2 . why shows the above error? how correct it?

Answer (score 1):

`do_action( 'after_setup_theme' );` doesn’t pass any parameter. You are cutting something of the length 0 after theme setup. Why?

Plus, your registration with `add_action` doesn’t tell WordPress that you want two parameters. The default is **one** parameter.

You don’t need this call at all. If you define the function in your `functions.php` it will be available in the loop.

Learn the [Plugin API](http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API), it isn’t so hard. :)

Always prefix you functions. Otherwise your users may get fatal errors when someone else has written a function with the same name.

If your function does what I think it does, you may have a look at my function [`utf8_truncate()`](https://gist.github.com/864355). No regex needed.

Comment: there is no do_action() in my function? how to write the add_action function. i am sorry. i am new to programme.add_action('after_setup_theme','cutstr()');. is this right?

Comment: once there was an error told me.the theme registers some custom functionality in the function warmHome_setup() however this function in not hooked so the functionality is not available. Recommend hooking the theme to the after_setup_theme hook.

Comment: so i think if i custom a function ,i should add this line after the function"add_action('after_setup_theme','cutstr()'). so could you tell me,when i should add the add_action. thank you

Comment: @enjoylife I added a note about the `add_action()` call. Read the Codex page about filters and actions. I cannot say it better.